# Current timestamp in mySQL is delayed by 30 minutes

Tags: mysql, sql, time, timestamp

I am trying to catch the current time by using current_timestamp query.

But it is returning the time delayed by 30 minutes.

So if there is any way to get the right time?
Or can I increment time automatically.

I have used this syntax.

Data type of time is `DATETIME`.
and also tried `TIMESTAMP`.

```
 UPDATE mytable SET time=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id=1;
```

Comment: The timestamp normally depents on the server configuration. Is the mysql server running on your computer or somewhere else?

Comment: Because you are in India, but your server is in Pakistan (or perhaps Bangladesh/India) See the manual for handling time zones properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely occurring because of the system timezone offset.

run this query to get the timezone offset of the system that mysql is running on

```
select timediff(now(),convert_tz(now(),@@session.time_zone,'+00:00'));
```

compare it with the timezone you are in.

Alternately you can run the following to get the correct time (replace the timezone with yours), but this means you would have to do it for every session.

```
SET time_zone='-06:00';
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. First query is not giving desired output but the second query is doing good work.

Comment: No problem. The first query was just there to allow you to check the timezone of the mysql server. If that timezone does not match up with the time zone you live in then you know its the system configuration for mysql that needs to be changed.